# is there a way to make a button cause a div to appear on the first click then disappear on the second click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, addeventlistener

I wonder if there is a way for the same button to make a div appear if I click on it once and disappear if I click on it another time
JS code:

```
const button = document.getElementById("menu");
const menu = document.querySelector(".box");
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  menu.style.display = "block";
});
```

HTML code:

```
<button id="menu">click me for menu!</button>
<div class="box"></box>
```

CSS code:

```
.box{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

I used this method before but I don't know if there is a way to use it directly

```
let clicks = 0;
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  checkclicks();
  if (clicked === true) menu.style.display = "block";
  if (clicked === false) menu.style.display = "none";
});
function checkclicks() {
  clicks += 1;
  if (clicks % 2 === 1) {
    //on
    clicked = true;
  }
  if (clicks % 2 === 0) {
    //off
    clicked = false;
  }
}
```

***EDIT
I want it to be hidden by default and only appearing when I click on the button and gets hidden again when I click on the same button***

Comment: What happens when you click it a third time? Is it just toggling the visibility of the div?

Comment: General advice: Don't use a global variable, the function should return a value.

Comment: Instead of assigning the style, use a class. Then you can use `.classList.toggle()` to add and remove the class.

Comment: how many `<div class="box"></box>` do you have in your HTML ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `classList.toggle` to toggle `hidden` class to your div with each click

```js
    var mydiv = document.querySelector("#mydiv")
    var mybtn = document.querySelector("#mybtn")

    mybtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
       mydiv.classList.toggle("hidden")
    });
```

```css
.hidden{
display:none;
}

#mydiv{
height:50px;
width:50px;
color:white;
background-color:blue;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="hidden">test</div>
<button id="mybtn">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: this is nice but i want it as default hidden and when i click the button it appears and when i click on it again it goes away but if i used this it will be visible by default

Comment: Add `hidden` class to your `div` in HTML code by default. Look at the solution, I updated it for you